# Creating a Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, c++14

So I have to crate a linked list for my project to add and multiply really big numbers. Bur I'm having a problem with creating a linked list. I have to get some output, but I cannot. And I cannot find a problem. It doesn't give an error, but also I cannot get any output as well. And I've compared with Linked List examples I could find, but still I cannot find the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct LLnode{
    int data;
    struct LLnode *next;
    LLnode (int);
};

LLnode::LLnode(int value){
    data = value;
    next = NULL;
}

class LinkedList{
private:
        LLnode *head, *tail, *temp;
public:
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    ~LinkedList();
    void createLLnode(int value);
    void display();
    void addToHead(int value);
    void deleteHead();
};

void LinkedList::createLLnode(int value){
    temp -> data = value;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else {
        tail -> next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
};

void LinkedList::display(){
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->data << "\n";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
};

void LinkedList::addToHead(int value){
    temp ->data = value;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
};

void LinkedList::deleteHead(){
    temp = head;
    head = head -> next;
    delete temp;
};

int main(){
    LinkedList* myList = new LinkedList();

    myList->createLLnode(8);
    myList->addToHead(12);
    myList->display();
    myList->deleteHead();
    myList->display();
    myList->addToHead(46);
    myList->addToHead(17);
    myList->display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't give any error" Segmentation fault is quite an error to me. Hint: you have a `delete`, but you never use any `new` inside `LinkedList`.

Comment: The first `createLLnode` call exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `temp`

Comment: Is the requirement to write your own linked list or is it just to add and multiply really big numbers?  If you do not have to write your own linked list then consider using  `std:list` if you really want to use a list or preferably `std::vector`.

Comment: `temp` should not be a member of your class.

Comment: *So I have to crate a linked list for my project to add and multiply really big numbers* -- Why do you need a linked list to do this?  This can be done using arrays or vectors, or even strings of digits.  Instead you're fighting two battles, getting a linked list to work, and then figuring out how to multiply big numbers.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to use `struct` when declaring variables of a structure.

Answer (score 2):

`LLnode *head, *tail, *temp;` are all pointers. This is fine for `head` and `tail`, but you seem to be using `temp` wrong, as you never allocate any memory for your nodes.

In the function `void LinkedList::createLLnode(int value)` you assign values to `temp`, but don't create a new object. The first line of the function should read

```
void LinkedList::createLLnode(int value) {
    temp = new LLnode;
    ...
```

In your `LinkedList` destructor you must then add code that iterates through your linked list and `delete`s all nodes.

Comment: Worth also saying that `temp` should not be a member variable. It should be local to the functions in which it is used.